# help interpreting SSD state

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

unknown@unknown-Z96S:~$ sudo smartctl -a /dev/sdb
gives me:

```
MART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       29102699295398
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       1250
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   000   000   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1249
225 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26627
232 Available_Reservd_Space 0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
233 Media_Wearout_Indicator 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       26627
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       29251
249 Unknown_Attribute       0x0013   100   100   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       1316
```

i expected to see something like 15000 in Power_On_Hours instead of 29102699295398. and Media_Wearout_Indicator gives 0. so 0% remaining of ssd life?!?

is this data full of errors? and how can i get normal ssd readings?

Answer (score 1):

If the SSD is an Intel, than this is a known firmware bug. See more info about this issue [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/smartmontools/wiki/FAQ#ThePower_On_HoursAttributeofmynewIntel520SSDreports890000hours).

Comment: it is Intel 330